# moving text to next line in vi

Tags: vim, vi

There is a line in Shell script

```
f) SCREEN = TRUE
```

and I want to make it

```
f)
SCREEN = TRUE
```

I cannot do this very easily in vi. Obviously in a normal text editor enter command can shift the text after f) to the next line. What is the best way to do it in vi?

Comment: It seems you don't know how to use vim very well. I recommend using `vimtutor` to learn the basics

Comment: Use this: `/f)<ENTER>a<ENTER>` -> search for `f)`, hit enter, hit `a`, hit enter...

Comment: Once you are on the space you want to break press `r<cr>`. `r` will replace one character with the next key you press. Quick way to get to the space is `0f<space>`. I agree with FDinoff, `vimtutor` would be a good place to learn the basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press `l` to move the cursor right and `j` to move the cursor down to get the cursor to the S.  Then press `i` to "insert" and hit enter to create a new line.  Then hit `esc` to stop inserting and `:wq` to save and quit.

[There are lots of basic vi command lists on the internet that might help.](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html)

Comment: This is the most complicated piece of software in the world. Why make things harder? Hmm? And it doesnt event have a "get started or tips page". I always avoid this in favor of Nano.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out if there was a way to do this in normal mode without pressing 3 buttons to insert, move the down line with enter and then escape to normal. I believe this is what OP may have been asking for. Not sure why there aren't any built in shortcuts for this.. Anyways I just ended up making a quick mapping in my .vimrc.

`nmap <leader>j i<cr><esc>`

Answer (score 0):

With your cursor on the line, `0fSi<ENTER><ESC>` 
(`0` Go to beginning of line, `fS` find 'S', `i` enter insert mode, `<ENTER>` insert some kind of newline, `<ESC>` exit insert mode)